# Print Specific Column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I think previously i didnt explain clearly. I have following file with space delimited. and i like to print only column1 and 3 info

/fs1               owner1

/fs2    app2     owner2

/fs3    app3     owner3

cat file-name | awk '{print $1 " " $3}' 
will only print

/fs1
/fs2 owner2
/fs3 owner3

Because of space delimited on first line awk is taking owner1 as column two and column 3 is empty. what i am looking for is to print file as

/fs1 owner1
/fs2 owner2
/fs3 owner3

Comment: We can understand the solution you are looking for, but not the *problem* that you are having. Please explain what it is you've tried, and what you think is not working, including any *relevant* code for the example.

Comment: You have tagged the question with `awk`, did you try using it?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you could also use `awk '{print $1, $NF}'` to print the first and last column.

Comment: If i have another extra column and now i like to print column 1,3 and 4 how it will work

Comment: If it's always the last and second last columns, you could use $NF and $(NF-1), respectively. However, if there could be more columns, you would have to find the right delimiter to separate the fields correctly (tabs, spaces, ..).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the deliminator as  "\t" as follows with `awk`
and after that you can print the columns that you need as below:

`awk -F"\t" '{print $1" "$3" "$4}'`

Comment: Replace the hard-coded `" "` with`,` between output fields.

Comment: The deliminator is of his choice but i posted that just to give a POC of how to do it with awk. Thnx for noticing anyway @EdMorton

Comment: The point is that is NOT how you'd do it with awk. The way you'd do it in awk is `{print $1, $3, $4}`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a fixed number of spaces between the fields you can:

```
cut -c 1-4,15-25 filename | sed -r 's/ +/ /'
```

This removes the middle text in columns 5-14, then puts a single space between the first and last fields.